# JPA ElementCollection with join on only one column from composite key

Tags: hibernate, jpa-2.0

The persistence framework JPA 2.0, with Hibernate 4.0 as provider.

Table X has columns A, B and C as a composite primary key and no other columns. Table Y has columns C, D and E. E is the primary key. I want the entity for X to have a collection of entities from Y that match on column C. This is a many to many relationship. A JPA relationship is not possible since it would require a join table. I have been trying to get an ElementCollection to work, but it keeps trying to do the join on A, B and C. If I put a ReferencedColumnName in the JoinColumn of the CollectionTable then it complains that ReferencedColumnName is not mapped to a single property. Every source I could find says this is not supported. There are a couple of important conditions. First, the entities are read only. No updates or inserts will be done. Second, I cannot make any changes to the database structure. Third I am trying to obtain a list of X entities that match on a specific value of A.

Given all of this, two ideas come to mind.

The first is to create the join from within the code. In other words query X.A = 'a' and then loop through the results querying on X.C = Y.C.

The second is to create an Z entity having the field A as a primary key and then within it put a ManyToMany relationship with table Y using table X as the join table.

How would you approach this situation?